# OpenCV - Error at hybridtrackingsample.cpp sample

Tags: c++, opencv, sample

i am trying to run this sample, from the opencv folder named cpp. As i mentioned in the titles its name is hybridtrackingsample.cpp

I am not uploading the code here because it has some problems with the format on the post, it gets a bit messy. You can find the code here: http://fossies.org/unix/misc/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.gz:a/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/hybridtrackingsample.cpp

or of course on your opencv sample folder.

The error i am getting is this one.

> ./test live
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   Opened camera
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
>   OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown feature type) in CvFeatureTracker, file /home/stefos/opencv2/modules/contrib/src/featuretracker.cpp, line 70
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/stefos/opencv2/modules/contrib/src/featuretracker.cpp:70: error: (-5) Unknown feature type in function CvFeatureTracker
>   Aborted

Any idea on what is going wrong?

I have to mention that the Invalid argument thing that is listed above is repeated at all projects that includes camera use even if the project runs without errors.

Answer (score 3):

I see an error in opencv 2.4.3 at OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/contrib/src/featuretracker.cpp near line 61, in the CvFeatureTracker method/function, where it appears the programmer left off two (needed) "break;" statements in the C++ switch statement there.

In OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/contrib/src/featuretracker.cpp near line 61,

before the

```
case CvFeatureTrackerParams::SURF:
```

and

```
default:
```

add a break; ...

Then rebuild/install opencv.

That got my hybridtrackingsample.cpp example running fine. (Remember not to left-click without dragging too. If you don't drag (to select a sub-area) hybridtrackingsample dies trying to process an empty rectangle...)

Comment: Same bug is still in 4.6.1 source.